# my gem evaluates two times

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hi yesterday I have sent my first gem to the world, I call it "pierwszytestowygemkaska" (FirstTestGemByMe) the name was on purpose long and bad, since it was a test gem.

I have use boundler to create project skeleton.

My lib.rb code is:

```
require "pierwszytestowygemkaska/version"

module Pierwszytestowygemkaska
  # Your code goes here...

  class First_time_gem

    def brave_new_world

        puts "Hello World from Kazik!"

    end

  end

  kazik = First_time_gem.new
  kazik.brave_new_world()

end
```

Everything works fine gem was created, i was able to install it but when i required it in irb, I got:

```
2.1.1 :001 > require 'pierwszytestowygemkaska'
Hello World from Kazik!
Hello World from Kazik!
 => true
```

Here is a whole code: https://github.com/kask666/pierwszytestowygemkaska

My question is, why does it returns "Hello World from Kazik" twice? Since I call brave_new_world function only once.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a call to the `kazik.brave_new_world()` both from **pierwszytestowygemkaska/version.rb**, and **pierwszytestowygemkaska.rb** files, so you get it twice.

Please be more carefully, and try not wasting the code =)